Evaluating the cardinality of a set involving complex numbers.
Let's say we have a set $ S = \{e^{i 2\pi \theta}: \theta \; \text {is a rational number} \} $
then, what can be said about the cardinality of the set defined as
$$ R = \{z^{n!} \, | \, z \in S \, \text{and}\, n \in \mathbb{N} \} $$
What I found is that since $\theta$ is a rational number say we have, $\theta = \frac{p}{q}$ where, $q \in \mathbb{N}$ and $p \in \mathbb{Z}$ then for any $z \in S$ we have,
$$\large z^{n!} = e^{i 2\pi \frac{p}{q} n!}$$
Now, for all $n \geq q$ we have $z^{n!} = 1$ so there are only finite choices of n for each $z \in S$. But S is countable. Therefore R is atmost countable.
But I am not sure here whether R is countably infinite or just finite, since the countable union of finite sets is not necessarily countably infinite it can be finite also.

Taking $n=1$, we see that $S$ is contained in $R$, so $R$ is countably infinite.

$S= \{z^{n!} \mid z \in S \land n=1 \} \subseteq R$ so $\vert R \vert \geq \vert S \vert$.  $S$ is infinite, so $R$ must also be infinite.  You have already demonstrated that $R$ is countable, so $R$ is countably infinite.
In fact, for rational $\theta, \theta \cdot n!$ is also rational, so $R \subseteq S$, allowing us to conclude that $R=S$.
